# Can JQuery File upload be used without AJAX?

Tags: file-upload, forms, jquery-file-upload

I want to use something along the lines of [JQuery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) (i'm open minded) in a form with lots of other fields for the UI (ex. image previews, delete, file sizes .etc), but I want to submit the files along with the form as if i used a normal HTML file field.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: It is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386082/blue-imps-jquery-file-upload-send-files-with-form-like-normal-field

Answer (score 1):

If you `console.log()` the form after submission you will get an object in return that has a bunch of information. Among that information you can find for example file information of the file you just upload.

You can check this http://jsfiddle.net/1r0Lprkj/1/ and open your console after you've submitted the form.

Then if you want to go deeper into this, then you can check out the Javascript FileReader which lets you do a bunch of cool stuff with the uploaded file. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

To answer your question; Yes it is possible to achieve without AJAX.

Comment: Is there anything already implemented to do it, or just better, an option to make jquery-file-upload not use AJAX to upload the file?